# How to put the Iso Data in dd-mm-YYYY format

Tags: kubuntu

I am new to Linux and would like to put the date in my Kubuntu in the formed dd-mm-YYYY, but when I put in the settings in Data Iso format, it appears to me YYYY-mm-dd.

Answer (score 1):

You did not give your location nor the language used when you installed ubuntu.

Neither date format you propose is the default for users in the US which gives mm-dd-yyyy.

Go to settings -> region and language.  There you can play with the formats setting to get what you want.  I have not tried it but possibly the UK settings?

Comment: Sorry Computer, forgot to put in the post. I am from Brazil and our language is Portuguese. I went where you said, changed the settings but did not change.